# Hide chat if in the same minute as the last chat in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

i have an assignment to create a chatbot using angular,i wanna do something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tVy0.png)

and currently here's what i got

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CJhO.png)

how to hide the time if new message is still in the same minute as the last one and if other user is not replying?

i wrap the chat messages with ng-container like this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index">
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'bot': message.author === 'bot',
  'user': message.author === 'user' }">
    <img *ngIf="message.author === 'bot'" class="avatar rounded-circle"
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/robot-face.png" alt="">
    <!-- <img *ngIf="message.author === 'user'" class="avatar rounded-circle" src="https://i.gifer.com/no.gif" alt="">
    <p style="padding: 0 !important;margin: 0 5px;font-weight: 500;">{{ message.author }}</p> -->
    <p style="padding: 0 !important;margin: 0 5px;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;"
      *ngIf='message.author == "bot"'>{{
      _chatbotName }}</p>
     // I WANNA HIDE THIS IF THE CHAT IS STILL ON THE SAME MINUTE AS THE LAST ONE
    <time class="time">{{ message.time | date:'shortTime' }}</time>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

anyone have an idea? any thoughts would be very helpful

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chat-auto-scroll-v3o3jx similar project to reproduce

EDIT

After i added the first solution, the time not showing up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cfCq.png)

EDIT 2

after a day using this solution, then i found something weird i also post this here [NgIf sometimes doesn't work properly using 2 condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470387/ngif-sometimes-doesnt-work-properly-using-2-condition) pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the index to access the previous message and compare it with the new one ?
you can try something like this

```
    // if you used the ' date.getHours() : date.getMinutes() ' 
    // (same as in the example given)
    // then check if they are not equal strings 
    
    
    <time class="time" *ngIf="message.time !== messages[i - 1].time">
                {{ message.time | date:'shortTime' }}
    </time>
```

Edit : check for the author too

```js
    <time class="time" 
           *ngIf="message.time === messages[i - 1]?.time && message.author !== messages[i-1]?.author">

       {{ message.time | date:'shortTime' }}
    
    </time>
```

Change `messages[i - 1]` to `messages[i - 1]?`

But this only applies if the data is `i > 0` so a little hack like this should do the trick:

```
<div *ngIf="i == 0" [ngClass]="{ 'bot': message.author === 'bot',
      'user': message.author === 'user' }">
        <time class="time">{{ message.time | date:'shortTime' }}</time>
      </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3prHX.png)

Comment: it says `Cannot read property 'time' of undefined`

Comment: it actually gives an error, i updated my question pls help

Comment: did you update that link ? , if yes than just remove the ' ? '

Comment: if i remove `?` it says `Cannot read property 'time' of undefined`

Comment: sorry thats irrelavant , i was following the link .. time of undefined happens when i < 1 and that ? verifies that before accessing it .. in the link you shared you had a ? before messages ..