# NgIf sometimes doesn't work properly using 2 condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Following this post [Hide chat if in the same minute as the last chat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436708/hide-chat-if-in-the-same-minute-as-the-last-chat-in-angular) i got an error like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgtiG.png)

the red line, times not showing up but then under it (green line) it showing up again. the green line was all i want, i'm using this ngIf statement

```
<div *ngIf="message.time === messages[i - 1]?.time && message.author !== messages[i-1]?.author" [ngClass]="{ 'bot': message.author === 'bot',
  'user': message.author === 'user' }">
<time class="time">{{ message.time | date:'shortTime' }}</time>
</div>
```

I thought it should works fine, but idk where did i do wrong,any idea?

EDIT 2

So i think the error is when the minutes changing see this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVJGo.png)

EDIT

I got similar question, i want to make time divider only shows once per day
[image]

here's how i code that

```
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="(message.time | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy') === (time  | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'); then today else showDate">
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #today>
    <p class="dividerDate">Today</p>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #showDate>
    <p class="dividerDate">{{ message.time }}</p>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you describe what your logic actually is, and what your arrays are? It's probably better to just have *ngIf="showTime()" and write some nicely structured logic in your component. Then not only is it possible to read what's going on but you could just debug it to fix it.

Comment: i can put function to ngIf? i didn't know that

Comment: Yes as long as it returns a boolean.

Comment: the idea is to hide the minute and avatar if the user input chat at the same minute before other user reply to it

Comment: ok i'll try to put this to function first

Comment: Doesn't your `showTime` method _always_ return an Array? And since `!![]` is always `true`, because it's an object, there is no real 'if' here.

Comment: yeah, i change my code and the question until i got the solution, did you got any? or an advice maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should check for diffèrent time not the opposite , the question wasnt that clear but try this

```
"message.time !== messages[i - 1]?.time || message.author !== messages[i-1]?.author"
```

if the author is different as the message or the time is different only then we would display the time

i hope this is the logic you need , if not expriment with only time and go from there for example display when ever the time is different regardless of the author

```
"message.time !== messages[i - 1]?.time"
```

Comment: yes ofc how can i forgot about that, using `||` is the right question thanks

Comment: i still have another similar question tho,would you help me?

Comment: i dont understand why cant you display it one time , plus when do you want to display it ? finally the code aqgain is not clear , i need to knwo its wrapper you can just copy any portion of code .

Comment: actually i have posted this on separate post, and i already got the answer thanks for helping tho